# How to use regplot to plot many regression plots for a dataframe in parts (say n rows)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, regression, seaborn

My df is something like df.head()

```
 index_hour    P2_Tam       P2_Qa
2019-01-09 16:40:00 2019-01-09 16:00:00   3.96375   52.234369
2019-01-09 16:41:00 2019-01-09 16:00:00   3.98825   51.204509
2019-01-09 16:42:00 2019-01-09 16:00:00   3.99325   50.290052
```

I want one regplot for every hour (index_hour) (P2_Tam vs P2_Qa). So for every 1 index hour, I want 1 regsplot . Is that possible in regplot?

I've tried:

```
sns.lmplot(x=df.P2_Tam,y=df.P2_Qa, hue='index_hour', data=df)
```

Is the use of hue correct?
Does regplot give that flexibility to plot multiple regplot for n rows??
Any other option using subplots n matplotlib?

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

---

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix can be looping over `groupby()`:

```
for hour, d in df.groupby('index_hour'):
    sns.lmplot(data=d, x='P2_Tam', y='P2_Qa')
```

You can also have a look at `sns.FacetGrid`

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: The `ValueError` comes from something else. Anywhere in your code you use `if df['somecols']`?

Comment: Yes to filter out the data of which I don't want regplot. But why is it generating this error?

Comment: Then the question is different, `df['somecol']` is a series, `if` only accepts `boolean` or those that can be converted to `boolean`. Pandas does **not** convert a series to boolean. Include that part and we can fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was a stupid mistake of syntax from my side. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped.  As the question is not entirely on the problem, consider deleting it.

Comment: However, the regplots are same for complete dataframe (just many in number) and not seperate for everyhour. I was expecting a seperate plot for every hour, and not same regplots for complete dataframe.

RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
  fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrow, ncol, **kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):